# How to get c++ own directory?

Tags: c++, linux, shared-libraries

I have a c++ .so file, so I called this from python. I wanna get .so file own location from c++ code. I used getcwd and readlink. They returned python code running directory. Is there someone knows the issue? Please help me, thanks.

P.s my .so file location is: /home/user/cpp/test.so 
my python code location is: /home/user/python/test.py
getcwd, readlink's output is : /home/user/python (i wanna get "/home/user/cpp")

Comment: There is no guaranteed way to get the directory where the shared library is stored - the nearest you'll get is to scan the LD_LIBRARY_PATH for the name, but beware that if you have multiple architectures, the first one you find may not be the one you are looking for (e.g. x86 rather than x86-64 or vice versa). Why do you think you need to know this?

Comment: There's also the real risk that you get a symbolic link to the .so file, instead of a hard link. Is that acceptable?

Answer (score 0):

In general, the easiest/most efficient way to find an executable's shared library dependencies - and their paths - is with the ["ldd"](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ldd) command.

If you want to get this information programmatically, one possibility is [dl_iterate_phdr](http://linux.die.net/man/3/dl_iterate_phdr)

Another is to check /proc/--pid--/maps:

http://www.unix.com/programming/34498-how-view-loaded-shared-libraries-running-processes-linux.html